# Use of symbols in predicate calculus

Tags: predicate-logic

Consider the following quantified proposition:

$$\exists x\ : R(x) \land T(x) $$

where $R(x)$ is 'x likes to paint in red,' $T(x)$ is 'x likes to live on a tree,' and $x$ is the domain of all monkeys.

Is the following a valid restatement of the above expression?

$$\exists x\ : R \land T $$

Answer (score 0):

If
$$ M =\mbox{the set of all monkeys} $$
$$ R(x) =x\ \mbox{likes to paint red} $$
$$ T(x) =x\ \mbox{likes to live on a tree} $$
Then I'd write it like this
$$\exists x\in M : R(x) \land T(x) $$
But if you choose to write 
$$\exists x\in M : R \land T $$
Your forcing the reader to assume that $x$ is the parameter of both $R$ and $T$, which is okay since $x$ is the only variable in this case.

So to directly answer your question, yes it's valid. My preference is to be clear, but to each their own.